# Scripting Git/GitHub actions for the less tech-literate

Tags: git, powershell, github, version-control

I have a github repo containing 3000 xml files and a team of editors to update them.

Some of the editors can be quite techphobic and I was hoping to script the push/pull/fetch operations with 2 shell scripts - say check_in.cmd and check_out.cmd.

I envisage the process as this:

1. Editor receives an update and creates a new branch locally named as per an agreed naming convention
2. Editor pulls down from github the latest version of the file that needs to be edited into the branch
3. Editor makes the edit and proofs it, and when satsfied ....
4. Editor commits the changes back to github
5. Editor merges the branch back to head

#1 and #2 would be in a check_out.cmd, and #4/#5 in check_in.cmd

Is that doable?
Is it recommended?
Is it bad practice?

TIA

Comment: Have you... talked to the users about this? Trying to impose the illusion of a complex synchronization model (svn-style check-in/check-out versioning) on top of an even more complex versioning paradigm (git) doesn't sound as attractive as you seem to think it is...

Comment: You think SVN might be a better fit? I was wondering about that myslef.

Comment: No, that's the _opposite_ of what I'm saying. My recommendation would be to educate them on how git works instead of trying to pretend that's not what they're using :-)

Comment: They have no interest in learning such stuff unfortunately

Comment: Is it worth noting that XML files are *already* heavily technical? 

Comment: The XML editor they use protects them from that

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good to me (from technical standpoint). I'd love to see some mandatory parameters in scripts, so that when non-techy-someone would run it, it would crash with a neat message like `Parameter BranchName was not provided. Specify it with -Name parameter (for example .\Script.ps1 -BranchName "NamingConventionName")` etc.

**BUT**

I worked with non-technical people providing them technical tools. These people don't like changes at all (don't we all? :)). Especially when it comes to processes and technical tools. So for me it'd be easier to make some kind of survey or call with people. Ask them what they need. Provide them options. As for the scripts themselves - remember that you'd have to ship these scripts somehow and manage their updates.

PS. I don't know how many changes do you have there. If many - I'd consider some lightweight webapp to change these XMLs on server-side, that would make the "current/legacy" versioning easier.
If there are many changes - I'd love to see this as "monkey-proof", so I'd do a .NET desktop app packed with installer using WiX ;)
But I don't know how many changes and how many users are in this process, so I don't know if it isn't a cannon for killing a fly.